# google play 2014 scroll to hide top image

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I´m trying to create an app inspired in the google play app.
I have my

2. RelativeLayout 
                       - RelativeLayout: * Header(this is the one that will be hidden when scrolling).
                       - RelativeLayout
                                     * ListView

When I scroll down I want the header to be pushed up the screen and then my listview will occupy the whole screen and when I scroll up the header will return to its original position.

I am currently using this code, but it flickers when I´m somewhere at the top of the list.
    // Hide top relative layout
        list.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            int mPosition=0;
            int mOffset=0;

```
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            int position = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            View v = list.getChildAt(0);
            int offset = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

            if (mPosition < position || (mPosition == position && mOffset < offset)){
                // Scrolled up
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down);
                headerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else {
                // Scrolled down
                headerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Can anyone please help me? It will be appreciate. I don't know if I'm using the right layouts.
Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Have a look here: http://sysmagazine.com/posts/190102/

Comment: thanks, I don't wanna touch the actionbar (yet) I need to hide the header. do you know if there is a native way to achieve this ? or is it gonna be native in android L?